# Enforce automatic breaking of long lines and and indent broken lines

Tags: line-breaking, indentation

I have many tex documents like that below which I want to translate with `pdflatex`. The files are the output of a vim-plugin which generates formatted output from vim's internal syntax highlighting. The trouble is that the first line in the resulting pdf it not broken and extends over the page margins. Other lines, like the second one, are broken but after the break they are not indented to the present level (not surprising, of course). It should be indented at least to the level of the indent (spaces to be precise) of the level of `description`.

I could process the documents with scripts to make systematic changes like the proper indenting and the line breaking or need to know global settings which influence the behavior accordingly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[HTML]{xcolor}
\color[HTML]{000000}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\noindent \par
\noindent \textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\enskip{}}\textcolor[HTML]{AA5500}{jump}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{:=}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{proc}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{(}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{f}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{::}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{name}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{,}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{t0}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{::}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{numeric}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{,}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{t1}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{::}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{numeric}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{,}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{y0}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{::}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{list}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{(}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{numeric}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{)}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{,}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{N}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{::}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{posint}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{,}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{method}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{::}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{procedure}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{)}\par
\noindent \par
\noindent \textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\enskip{}}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\enskip{}}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{description}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\enskip{}}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{"It\enskip{}advances\enskip{}the\enskip{}solution\enskip{}y0\enskip{}at\enskip{}t0\enskip{}by\enskip{}N\enskip{}steps\enskip{}such\enskip{}that\enskip{}it\enskip{}reaches\enskip{}t1.\enskip{}The\enskip{}step-size\enskip{}h\enskip{}is\enskip{}adjusted\enskip{}correspondingly."}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{;}\par
\noindent \par
\noindent \textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\enskip{}}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{end}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\enskip{}}\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{proc}\textcolor[HTML]{0000AA}{;}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have solved the problem of indenting (at least partly). I replace the leading `\textcolor[HTML]{000000}{\enskip{}}` by `\setlength{\leftskip}{n*10pt}`, where `n*10pt` is the numeric value (in pt) I get when inserting for n the number of occurrences  of the original string.

Comment: My remaining problem is to break the long first string. Apparently it is related to that latex does not break the variable names (which is good), but it does also not break after the commas. This does not change if I insert spaces. Of course I could enforce it with `\\`, but I would prefer if latex would break this line automatically as needed.